# Spring loaded roller door latch

Tags: doors

This "spring loaded roller door latch" is old and not very effective. I'm trying to replace it but all my searches for those keywords turn up nothing like this. I also can't find a manufacturer name on the door. Questions:

1. Can this be repaired or is replace the best option? (If repair possible then how?)
2. If it needs to be replaced what do I search for to find the replacement?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with your search term, but try searching, "roller catch". You'll find a ton of choices.

(edit to add a couple of thoughts...)

Regarding repair versus replace: it's impossible at this distance to know, but replace usually is more predictable. (And in this case, probably not too expensive.)

And as a general rule, when I'm searching for something that I know exists, but I can't name it, I use google image search. Start with something similar, like "ball catch", and after a few pages of images, you'll probably see something like what you're really searching for. Then a few iterations later, you'll have found the most common name for the thing you're actually looking for.